# Merging and Sorting String Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to finish my assignment, but I am not sure how to complete it. 
I have 3 arrays in my code, each of which have first names and last names (the last name comes before the first one in the arrays).

Which function should I use in order to decided whether a string is before the other?
I was thinking compare, but I'm not too sure how to implement it.

This is my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String[] section1 = {"Curie, Marie", "Feynman, Richard", "Germain, Sophie",
            "Turing, Alan"};
    String[] section2 = {"Bolt, Usain", "Graf, Steffi","Hamm, Mia"};
    String[] section3 = {"Bach, Johann Sebastian", "Beethoven, Ludwig van",
            "Mozart, Wolfgang Amadeus", "Schumann, Clara"};

    String[] merged = mergeSortedArrays(section1, section2);
    String[] merged = mergeSortedArrays(merged, section3);

    for(int i = 0; i < merged.length(); i ++)
        System.out.print(merged[i]);



    }


 //Do not change the method header
public static String[] mergeSortedArrays(String[] a1, String[] a2)
{

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while(a1[i] != null && a2[j] != null)
    {
        if(a1[i] "comes before" a2[j])
        {
            merged[k] = a1[i];
            i++;
            else {
                merged[k] = a2[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        return merged;



    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare two strings, use

```
if(a1[i].compareTo(a2[j]) <= 0)  {   //Means: a1[i] <= a2[j]     
   System.out.println("a1[" + i + "] (" + a1[i] + ") is less-than-or-equal-to a2[" + i + "] (" + a2[i] + "));
}
```

Or

```
if(a1[i].compareTo(a2[j]) < 0)  {   //Means: a1[i] < a2[j]     
   System.out.println("a1[" + i + "] (" + a1[i] + ") is less than a2[" + i + "] (" + a2[i] + "));
}
```

I recommend the comments as I've done, because I find looking at the `compareTo` function very confusing. I have to keep reminding myself that the operator is sort of "in place" of the `compareTo`. I *always* comment it like this.

I've noticed some serious issues with your code, unrelated to string comparison:

- Your else has no close curly-brace before it.
- The object `merged` is never declared in the `mergeSortedArrays` function
- Your while loop needs to check that the array indexes are not too high given the arrays, or you're going to get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`
- `anArray.length()` is incorrect. Eliminate the parentheses.